# Generate a HTML document to display my data from c#

Tags: c#, html

I am try to develop a stand-alone EXE application to create a HTML document to display data which is obtained from some APIs using c#.

Can't seem to find a clear way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. If you need a library to control HTML in .NET you can take a look into HtmlAgilityPack: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack. yes i too used it. Best way

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library for using Standalone Razor for generating HTML using CSHTML as templates:

https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine